# Jointcollection for kinect SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, kinect

I am now upgrading my Kinect program from SDK 1.8 to 2.0. In my old version, I used jointcollection very often. However, I do not now how can I rewrite the program without using this function. My example code is attached below:

```
    private static ResultUnit ProcessKneeLeft(JointCollection joints)
    {
        ResultUnit result = new ResultUnit();
        result.State = GetTrackingState(new Joint[] { joints[JointType.KneeLeft], joints[JointType.HipLeft], joints[JointType.AnkleLeft] });
        if (result.State != TrackingState.NotTracked)
            result.Value = VectorFunc.Angle(joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position, joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position, joints[JointType.AnkleLeft].Position);
        return result;
    }
```

Please give me a hand. Thanks a lot!
Sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Joints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.joints.aspx) is the new `JointCollection` for kinect for windows V2. In kinect for windows V2, `Joints` is a property of [Body Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.body.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I can find the Body.Joints property in library. However, I still do not know how to implement this new function in my case, since I am naïve in C#. Can you please help me to update the code in the example code?

Comment: private static ResultUnit ProcessKneeLeft(Body body)
  {
   ResultUnit result = new ResultUnit();
   result.State = GetTrackingState(new Joint[] { body.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft], body.Joints[JointType.HipLeft], body.Joints[JointType.AnkleLeft] });
   if (result.State != TrackingState.NotTracked)
    result.Value = VectorFunc.Angle(body.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position, body.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position, body.Joints[JointType.AnkleLeft].Position);
   return result;
  }

Comment: is the above function working in your end? it should work.

Comment: Yes, I believe the code should work in this paragraph. However, this method is problematic in my case because I also called Jointcollection in outer nested function. For example,

Comment: public static ResultUnit GetAngle(JointCollection joints, JointAngleID id)
  {
   switch (id)
   {
    case JointAngleID.ShoulderLeftFE:
     return ProcessShoulderLeftForward(joints);

Comment: public static ResultUnit GetAngle(JointCollection joints, JointAngleID id)
{
 switch (id)
 {
  case JointAngleID.KneeLeft:
   return ProcessKneeLeft(joints);    
 }
}

double value = JointEvalFunc.GetAngle(skeleton.Joints, this.Flag).Value;
The GetAngle function is asking for joint parameter. However, the method I mentioned today forced me to put (Body body) rather than joint.
Can you please suggest an alternative method to make a declare statment before a function start rather that put the body as part of parameter?

Comment: You can pass `Joint` dictionary which works similar to `JointCollection` in SDK 1.8. Declare your function like `GetAngle(IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints, JointAngleID id) { // statements } `

Comment: You can have a glimpse on this [Kinect WPF C# project](https://gist.github.com/rafaftahsin/ec988963bb3dacf621ce) to understand how to fetch `Joint` data from kinect and use it as a parameter of a function.